# Where in Magento 2's Backend Can you Change the Expiration Time for an oAuth Token Request?

Tags: magento2, oauth, integration

As per Magento's [developer documentation site](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html#http-post)

> This is the first step in the 2-legged Oauth handshake. However, you must use these credentials to get an access token in fewer than three minutes or the credentials are disabled for security reasons. The credentials expiry can be changed from backend by the administrator. As stated previously, it's defaulted to three minutes.

it sounds like you can change the expiration time for an `OAuth` token request somewhere in the backend.

Where is this somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're looking for can be found under **Admin > Stores > Configuration > Services > OAuth tab**:

[image]

The interesting thing is that default value is not 3 minutes but actually 5 minutes (300 seconds).

The default values are set under `\app\code\Magento\Integration\etc\config.xml`:

```
<default>
    <oauth>
        <cleanup>
            <cleanup_probability>100</cleanup_probability>
            <expiration_period>120</expiration_period>
        </cleanup>
        <consumer>
            <expiration_period>300</expiration_period>
            <post_maxredirects>0</post_maxredirects>
            <post_timeout>5</post_timeout>
        </consumer>
        <authentication_lock>
            <max_failures_count>6</max_failures_count>
            <timeout>1800</timeout>
        </authentication_lock>
    </oauth>
</default>
```

Another interesting thing is that, on top of this default value, an extra default value is defined under `\app\code\Magento\Integration\Helper\Oauth\Data.php`:

```
const CONSUMER_EXPIRATION_PERIOD_DEFAULT = 300;
```

This value is used in case the expiry is set to a negative number:

```
public function getConsumerExpirationPeriod()
{
    $seconds = (int)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        self::XML_PATH_CONSUMER_EXPIRATION_PERIOD,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
    return $seconds > 0 ? $seconds : self::CONSUMER_EXPIRATION_PERIOD_DEFAULT;
}
```

NB: the screenshot is from a 2.0.0 install, I reckon an Authentication lock section has been added since.

Answer (score 3):

Kindly navigate to below path to change the oauth related settings from admin panel

**Stores -> configuration -> services -> oauth**